# Will three months of Muai Thai help?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, karate, mixed-martial-arts, muay-thai

In three months I'll be going abroad for master studies. I have left my job in order to prepare somewhat for the course in the three months before I leave. This gives me time for some extra activities to try on. I have started with swimming, but apart from that I want to start some martial arts training, which has been something I have been interested and wanted to start for the longest of time from my childhood but could not because it was not affordable. Now from working for the past 3 years and earning myself, I want to start with martial arts no matter what.

I am very certain that I won't master any martial arts in 3 months, that is not my intention either, my question is if I enroll for the three months will it be a waste? I plan to continue abroad as well, and after I settle in a new place and with my masters I will want to continue it, not really sure how much of a gap that will bring.

I have from my childhood heard of Karate, Taekwondo only, was planning to enroll in them but then I heard of Muai Thai, I felt very curious about it and now am very interested in it. I play football(soccer) 3 days a week, I have a pretty strong legs I feel.

If I opt for Muai Thai for the three months, will it be worth it for me, will the coming gap after it affect me for my future classes, should I go for something else ?

I am sorry if I made mistakes in some terms, I have had no training in no activity before in my life, I want to start with this as soon as I can.
Hopefully my question makes sense, Thank you.

Comment: Why are you planning to stop training while studying?

Comment: I am not planning to stop, but I am certain that I won't be able to join any institute pretty soon as I will have to find a place, settle down with new environment and always keep the course my priority. I am confident I will join there only if I begin something here.
So not sure about the gap if it is going to be a long one, or might be a very short one as well, but certainly there will be a gap,I just wanted to make sure if it is worth enrolling in it with my situation as the 3 month subscription here was expensive.
Hopefully everything turns out better than expected, thanks.

Comment: I saw a Muay Thai 3 month subscription in India for Rs.12000. That's more than double of what they should be charging you. As of 2019, it's reasonable if a school charges Rs.1500 to 2000 per month and approximately the same amount as a one-time non-refundable payment (which I think they use to do a background check on you). You might want to get familiar with McDojo's: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/6739/what-are-the-signs-that-a-dojo-could-be-classed-as-a-mcdojo

Comment: In my Area I have seen 24k for which I was asking for, till 25 is no issue for me, my worry was if it would be worth due to the gap of time that would follow after i leave here.Anyhow, its been positive replies as of yet, will wait some more and decide.Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Three months of Muai Thai can give you some basic knowledge of defending yourself. Once you learn it, you will automatically use it when under threat. Knowing how to raise your hands and knees to protect your groin, chest, face and solar plexus are by themselves very valuable pieces of knowledge.
I'm not sure how you'd be able to cope while simultaneously practicing swimming and soccer (muscles being tired) on the same day, but it's something you'd have to experiment with...perhaps alternate days. Don't push yourself too hard and make sure you get the necessary amount of protein in your diet. If you are already tired from swimming and soccer, don't go for Muai Thai.
Three months of this training is very unlikely to give you any special consideration when you join Muai Thai classes elsewhere after 6 months or a year. You'll be treated as a new student.  I don't see any other disadvantage of doing a 3 month stint. Just make sure the institute will allow you to join for just 3 months. Tell them upfront. You can say you want to try Muai Thai for few months to see if it's right for you.

Answer (score 3):

In martial arts training, every little bit helps. Since you have 0 martial arts knowledge and plan to have a few months gap after that, learn up the basics of the straight punch and kick. Nothing too fancy. Let your teacher know you might be training solo after the 3 months and ask him for pointers and ideas on what to do and what mistakes to watch out for.

In that gap time, you could do solo training like bagwork, shadow box, fitness and coordination drills. The list of solo training workouts for martial arts are only limited by your imagination.

Answer (score 2):

No waste at all. Go for it, train hard then find another club where you can continue.